# How can I invoke a go binary from Varnish

Tags: varnish

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url ~ "^/(?:settings|ttls|backends)/(?:reload|dump)/$") {
        if (client.ip ~ internal) {
            if (req.url == "/settings/reload/") {
...
```

assume this is what my vcl_recv looks like. On hitting a specific regex I want to invoke a go binary that imports specific settings. All this only happens during a cache miss.

As far as I have seen, invoking a foreign function interface in a VCL requires a VMOD.
Scourging the internet, I did not find any such VMOD.

The other way is to write a VMOD that helps us do that. Since I am not a C engineer by any means, I tried doing that with Golang and pretty much hit a wall.

Any suggestions??

Comment: Go binaries are just binaries, so this question isn't Go-specific (doesn't need a `go` tag).

Comment: got it, but do you know how can I invoke any binary from VCL?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any open source VMODs that can do this. However, Varnish Enterprise's `vmod_file` has support for this.

See https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/vmods/file/#return-the-uptime-of-the-server

#### Varnish Enterprise & Cloud disclaimer

Although Varnish Enterprise is a commercial product that requires purchasing a license, the official images in the Cloud don't require any upfront payment.

For the platforms mentioned below, the marketplace allows you to pay for hourly usage:

- [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/seller-profile?id=263c0208-6a3a-435d-8728-fa2514202fd0&ref=dtl_pcp_sold_by)
- [Azure](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/varnish.varnish-enterprise?tab=Overview)
- [GCP](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/browse?q=varnish%20software)

This allows you to test `vmod_file` (and other features) without having to set aside a budget for an enterprise license.